# Why doesn't my template accept an initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I have created a template as follows

```
template<typename T>
void f(T const& t) { }
```

I wanted for this to be callable by containers but also by initializer lists. I thought it would be `initializer_list<int>`, when called as follows.

```
f({1, 2, 3});
```

But GCC behaves as if it's not Standards compliant

```
m.cpp: In function 'int main()':
m.cpp:6:25: warning: deducing 'const T' as 'const std::initializer_list<int>'
m.cpp:4:6: warning:   in call to 'void f(const T&) [with T = std::initializer_list<int>]'
m.cpp:6:25: warning:   (you can disable this with -fno-deduce-init-list)
```

Can anyone explain how I can make this work without warnings? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm seems unfortunate that SO thinks `initializer_list` tag is synonymous to `initializer-list` -.- C++0x will drop tears!

Comment: AFAICS, it's not defined as a a synonym at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/initializer-list/synonyms. Is there some built-in logic which replaces `x_y` by `x-y`?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I just saw http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75798/unfortunate-auto-detection-of-synonyms-for-initializer-list

Comment: I will just use std::initializer_list

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A "thing" like {1,2,3} does not qualify as an expression. It has no type. Therefore, no type deduction is done. But C++0x makes an explicit exception for 'auto', so

```
auto x = {1,2,3};
```

actually works and decltype(x) will be `initializer_list<int>`. But this is a special rule that only applies to auto. I guess they wanted to make loops like these

```
for (int x : {2,3,5,7,11}) {
   ...
}
```

work since this kind of loop exploits the special rule.

As for solving the problem, you could add an `initializer_list<T>` overload as a "wrapper":

```
template<class T>
inline void outer(initializer_list<T> il) {
   inner(il);
}
```

I didn't test this but my current understanding is that it should work.

Comment: The special rule mentioned is in 7.1.6.4 `auto' specifier [dcl.spec.auto]

Comment: `C++0x makes an explicit exception for 'auto'` Yeah, in both the assignment-like syntax that you showed, and also the `auto something{a, b, c}` form. The latter has been an inconsistent pain in the posterior that is only now going to be fixed with C++17, where `auto something{blah}` without the `=` symbol means _'create an object of `decltype(blah)`, initialised from `blah`_ - not the current meaning of _'create an `initializer_list` called `something` with one element of the same type as `blah`'_. Finally! But by this point it means a lot of updating to affected codebases. :C

Answer (score 3):

Well, [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno_002ddeduce_002dinit_002dlist-132) says that

> This option is present because this deduction is an extension to the current specification in the C++0x working draft, and there was some concern about potential overload resolution problems.

This information may simply be outdated (according to the source it was last updated in 2008). As far as I understand this, the deduction was included into GCC but with the expectation that a later draft of the standard would remove the rule, or at least limit it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain how I can make this work without warnings?

I don't know if `this` refers to the exact code you quoted, or if you just want to know how you can instantiate the function template with an initializer list without triggering warnings, but if it's the latter and if the problem is merely *deducing* the correct type, you could possibly avoid it by just calling

```
f<initializer_list<int>>({1, 2, 3});
```

It's not pretty, but it might avoid the warning without fiddling with the compiler command line arguments.

I'd probably put a comment nearby which explains that you don't rely on the compiler deducing the correct type due to weaknesses in certain GCC versions.