# Templates don't always guess initializer list types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

```c
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

void foo(std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>) {}
template <class T> void bar(T) {}

int main() {
    foo({{0,1}});  //This works
    foo({{0,1},{1,2}});  //This works
    bar({{0,1}});  //This warns
    bar({{0,1},{1,2}});  //This fails
    bar(std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>({{0,1},{1,2}}));  //This works
}
```

This doesn't compile in gcc 4.5.3, it gives a warning for the marked line saying `deducing ‘T’ as ‘std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >’` and an error for the marked line saying `no matching function for call to ‘bar(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`.  Why can gcc deduce the type of the first call to bar but not the second, and is there a way to fix this other than long and ugly casting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my template accept an initializer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757614/why-doesnt-my-template-accept-an-initializer-list) - That question is basically a duplicate. The fact that type deduction is being done at all on an initializer list is a g++ extension.

Comment: @Omnifarious not sure whether these are dupes. my question was intended to ask for less details than apparently this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GCC according to C++11 *cannot deduce the type for either first two calls to `bar`*. It warns because it implements an **extension** to C++11.

The Standard says that when a function argument in a call to a function template is a `{ ... }` and the parameter is not `initializer_list<X>` (optionally a reference parameter), that then the parameter's type cannot be deduced by the `{...}`. If the parameter *is* such a `initializer_list<X>`, then the elements of the initializer list are deduced independently by comparing against `X`, and each of the deductions of the elements have to match.

```
template<typename T>
void f(initializer_list<T>);

int main() {
  f({1, 2}); // OK
  f({1, {2}}); // OK
  f({{1}, {2}}); // NOT OK
  f({1, 2.0}); // NOT OK
}
```

In this example, the first is OK, and the second is OK too because the first element yields type `int`, and the second element compares `{2}` against `T` - this deduction cannot yield a constradiction since it doesn't deduce anything, hence eventually the second call takes `T` as `int`. The third cannot deduce `T` by any element, hence is NOT OK. The last call yields contradicting deductions for two elements.

One way to make this work is to use such a type as parameter type

```
template <class T> void bar(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> x) {
  // ...
}
```

I should note that doing `std::initializer_list<U>({...})` is dangerous - better remove those `(...)` around the braces. In your case it happens to work by accident, but consider

```
std::initializer_list<int> v({1, 2, 3});
// oops, now 'v' contains dangling pointers - the backing data array is dead!
```

The reason is that `({1, 2, 3})` calls the copy/move constructor of `initializer_list<int>` passing it a temporary `initializer_list<int>` associated with the `{1, 2, 3}`. That temporary object will then be destroyed and die when the initialization is finished. When that temporary object that is associated with the list dies, the backing-up array holding the data will be destroyed too (if the move is elided, it will live as long as "v"; that's bad, since it would not even behave bad guaranteedly!). By omitting the parens, `v` is directly associated with the list, and the backing array data is destroyed only when `v` is destroyed.

Comment: I didn't understand the last paragraph. Could you elaborate on that a bit more? I don't see any difference between `std::initializer_list<int> v({1, 2, 3});` and `std::initializer_list<int> v{1, 2, 3};`. They look same to me.

Comment: @Nawaz i thought I elaborated on it the most that I can. If you have still questions, I recommend to open a new question, because the elaboration necessary will warrant a new answer.

Comment: @Nawaz did you open a new question for the last paragraph? May you can forward it here in the comments.

Comment: @SebTu: No. I think, I didn't.

Comment: @SebTu I'm not sure about the state of this in the most recent Standard (C++14) and with the "guaranteed copy elision" in C++17. So asking a separate question on that is certainly a good idea. I will watch it and correct or extend my answer, if it's wrong regarding C++14 or 17

Answer (score 5):

List initialization relies on knowing what type is being initialized. `{1}` could mean many things. When applied to an `int`, it fills it with a 1. When applied to a `std::vector<int>`, it means to create a one-element `vector`, with `1` in the first element. And so on.

When you call a template function who's type is completely unconstrained, then there is no type information for list initialization to work with. And without type information, list initialization cannot work.

For example:

```
bar({{0,1}});
```

You expect this to be of the type `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>`. But how could the compiler know that? `bar`'s first parameter is an unconstrained template; it can literally be *any* type. How could the compiler possibly guess that you meant this specific type?

Quite simply, it can't. Compilers are good, but they're not clairvoyant. List initialization can only work in the presence of type information, and unconstrained templates remove all of that.

By all rights, that line should have failed to compile, according to C++11. It cannot deduce what type you intended the `{...}` to be, so it should have failed. That looks like a GCC bug or something.

Comment: This will not work because the compiler has no idea what it shall deduce `T` to if it only has `std::pair<T, T>` and `{1, 2}`. I like how you describe the problem in the first part of your answer. The same rationale applies for how to get `T` for `pair<T, T>` :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Fair enough. Removed.