# Templated initialization_list - why does lookup fail

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

Given

```
#include <utility>
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void foo(std::initializer_list<std::pair<T1, T2>> _a, std::initializer_list<T3> _b) {
    /* ... */
}

int main() {
        foo({{1,2},{3,4}},{1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

why does gcc 4.6 produce the error

`error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`

`note: candidate is`

`note: template<class T1, class T2, class T3> void foo(std::initializer_list<std::pair<T1, T2> >, std::initializer_list<T3>)`

**Update**
Now works when

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::pair<T1, T2> p(const T1& _1, const T2& _2) {
    return std::make_pair(_1, _2);
}
```

is added and `{{1,2},{3,4}}` is replaced with `{p(1,2), p(3,4)}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Templates don't always guess initializer list types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699963/templates-dont-always-guess-initializer-list-types)

Comment: Isn't template deduction for intializer_list<T> more restrictive than plain T? Granted, it's non-trivial in both cases, so I can see where it can be seen as duplicate.

Comment: the issue is not the usage of `initializer_list<T>` compared to `T`, but the usage of `{....}` as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is basically *chained* conversion/invocation, which is not allowed in C++.

First you want to convert this,

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

into this (while deducing the *type* argument),

```
{std::pair<int,int>{1,2},std::pair<int,int>{3,4}}
```

which then into `std::initializer_list`.  It is not allowed.

You've to do one conversion yourself:

```
foo( {std::pair<int,int>{1,2},std::pair<int,int>{3,4}}, {1,2,3,4,5});
```

then it will compile : http://ideone.com/bRJqV

Comment: You meant `template <typename T1, typename T2> std::pair<T1, T2> p(const T1& _1, const T2& _2) { return std::make_pair(_1, _2); }`. Let's keep the instantiations to a minimum :)

Comment: This does not accurately explain the reason for the compile error. See the duplicate link given above for why this does not work.