# Initializer list in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921335/use-brace-enclosed-initializer-lists-in-a-variadic-template?lq=1) says that braced-init lists cannot be used in template arguments. What if there is an explicit initializer list specialization?

I am trying to write a reduce-like function that would accept the following syntax:
`f(1, {2}, {3,4,5}, 6)`. My attempt is:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename... Rest>
int add(int acc, std::initializer_list<int> list, Rest... rest) {
    auto res = acc;
    for (auto i : list) res += i;
    return add(res, rest...);
}

template <typename... Rest>
int add(int acc, int n, Rest... rest) {
    return add(acc+n, rest...);
}

int add(int result) { return result; }

int main() {
    int result = add(1, {2}, 3, {4, 5, 6});
}
```

but the braced-init list is not interpreted as a constructor for initializer list.

Is there any other way I can make this syntax work?