# specializing function template on initializer_list does not work?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, explicit-specialization

> **I know specializing function templates is [wrong](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)**

This question is out of Curiosity.

say I have a function template

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T){}
```

and I specialize it

```
template<>
void foo(std::initializer_list<int>){}
```

and I call this like

```
foo({1, 2, 3});
```

I get an error "no instance of foo matching brac-enclosed **initializer list**" pointing to the primary template
(overloading works fine as expected)

but if I change the function **base** template to taking initializer_list as parameter everything is ok.

what exactly is happening?

compiler : gcc 4.8.2
[helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699963/templates-dont-always-guess-initializer-list-types)

Comment: @Casey oh i dint realise that. thanks.

Comment: Actually compilers are perfectly allowed to do that if you pass in an actual `std::initializer_list<foo>` object. They are forbidden to deduce `initializer_list` (or anything else) from the syntactic initializer list. Basically, passing `{ whatever }` to a `f(T)` doesn't work.

Comment: @SebastianRedl ah understood. but dint realise that because i was thinking that the specialization will catch this list. i knew explicitly qualifying will work but dint understand this point. basically `{ whatever}` doesnt work even for aggregate and POD types when it comes to deduction right?

Comment: Specializations are taken into account _after_ overload resolution picks the base template.

Comment: @Xeo does this go for overloads too? i mean are the overloads are matched first ?

Comment: Yes. Overload resolution picks the best matching function, and if that's a template, checks for specializations.