# Initialising std::pair<double, std::array<std::pair<double, double>, 3> >

Tags: c++, std-pair, stdarray

Can anyone advise on the correct syntax for the std::make_pair call in the std::vector::push_back call in the code below:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<double, double> PairType;
    std::vector<std::pair<double, std::array<PairType, 3> > > myVector;

    double Key = 0.0;
    PairType Pair1 = std::make_pair(1.0, 2.0);
    PairType Pair2 = std::make_pair(3.0, 4.0);
    PairType Pair3 = std::make_pair(5.0, 6.0);

    myVector.push_back(std::make_pair(Key, { Pair1, Pair2, Pair3 } )); // Syntax Error

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (MS VS2015.2) cannot determine the type of the second argument in the std::make_pair call, which is understandable yet I don't know how to enlighten it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my template accept an initializer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757614/why-doesnt-my-template-accept-an-initializer-list)

Comment: Note that you don't need make_pair:  `myVector.push_back({Key, { Pair1, Pair2, Pair3 } });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the compiler cannot figure out that `{ Pair1, Pair2, Pair3 }` is an `std::array` of three pairs. Specifying the type explicitly should work:

```
myVector.push_back(std::make_pair(Key, std::array<PairType,3>{ Pair1, Pair2, Pair3 } ));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/XGdHjO)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [std::experimental::make_array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array), if the compiler supports [Library fundamentals v2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2):

```
using std::experimental::make_array;
myVector.push_back(std::make_pair(Key, make_array(Pair1, Pair2, Pair3) ));
```

[LIVE from GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64f9b16a15ca7f0b)

Comment: Or just write `make_array` as it is not that long.

Comment: @Yakk With a `using std::experimental::make_array;`? Sure.

Comment: no, write the implementation, if you do not have it.  It is a short function.